# Is drywall under a stairwell required to be taped?

Tags: drywall, stairs

My basement is finished with space under the stairs closed in with its own door access. There is 3/4" drywall fully in place on ceiling and walls, but not taped.

Does this need to be taped or is the drywall enough in terms of meeting fire code?

Comment: enough for what?

Comment: Will have to see if your local fire code addresses this.  If used as a fire block then need the tape and mud.  If not, my opinion is it looks nicer, even for a place for junk.

Comment: Thanks for the link, so it should be taped and mudded at a minimum. Ok thank you!

Comment: It's probably 5/8" drywall, and that raises questions about whether it's a firewall. You don't normally see 5/8" on residential walls _except_ for firewalls, but they're normally only against a garage. You'd have to give us more detail for answers to be confident at all.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely YES. It's an egress stair in case of fire. Consider what if - how to exit the lower level safely if a fire starts in the enclosed space below the stairs. Probably a minimum of ½" drywall is required for under stair protection where the area under the stair is framed in and has an entry door or access panel.